# MVC 3 sub Site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7

I have a very basic site that works fine on its own but when I create a duplicate of the site and attempt to add it to a sub domain (then convert it to a application) I get a error when I attempt to any controller which has the below settings at the top:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{

    // This constructor is used by the MVC framework to instantiate the controller using
    // the default forms authentication and membership providers.
    private CustomMembershipDB datacontext;
    public AccountController()
        : this(null, null)
    {
        datacontext = new CustomMembershipDB();
    }
    // This constructor is not used by the MVC framework but is instead provided for ease
    // of unit testing this type. See the comments at the end of this file for more
    // information.
    public AccountController(IFormsAuthentication formsAuth, IMembershipService service)
    {
        FormsAuth = formsAuth ?? new FormsAuthenticationService();
        MembershipService = service ?? new AccountMembershipService();
    }

    public IFormsAuthentication FormsAuth
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public IMembershipService MembershipService
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
```

Error I get:

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: The entry 'EFMembershipProvider' has already been added.

IIS seems to be complaining about a duplicate Membership provider being set on the same domain and not sure simply renaming it will solve this one? Any Idea appreciated as I'm a newbie and this is above me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that your "subsite" is a virtual directory of the first one. Root's `Web.config` settings are inherited to virtual directories.

That means that by default your subsite gets all providers declared in your top site.

To prevent this behavior you can use this [directive](http://aspdotnetfaq.com/Faq/how-to-disable-web-config-inheritance-for-child-applications-in-subfolders-in-asp-net.aspx) `inheritInChildApplications=false` on your main `Web.config` or simply avoid to (re)declare the `EFMembershipProvider` in your subsite.